# Django Form Coding Style Guide

Tags: django, forms, coding-style

As we know, the Django authors provide a [coding style guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/), to use as guidance when writing Django applications. However, the document provided mentions nothing specifically about forms.

Is there already a common pattern in use for this? Is the best to follow the Model style guide, with some minor adaptions? Below is how I define forms at the moment, and looking through a random selection of popular Django apps, I fail to see much consistency that agrees with my method. Can those using Django for many years now provide a recommendation?

```
class ExampleForm(BetterModelForm):
    # start with field definitions, as with Django Model style guide
    name = forms.CharField(label="Your Name")
    town = forms.CharField(label="Ideal city?")

    class Meta:
        # all Meta class definitions, as with Django Model style guide
        model = models.Example
        fields = ['name', 'town', 'example_field']

    def save(self):
        # ...

    def clean_name(self):
        # ...

    def clean_town(self):
        # ...

    def clean(self):
        # ...

    def custom_function(self):
        # ...
```

So, my style is to start with the fields, then the Meta class (with a clear line before the definition), then the save method, then any clean methods, and then any custom methods. Is this close to the standard, recommended way of doing it, if such a thing exists?

Comment: I don't think it matters, but for semantic reasons I define the same structure as Model classes, after all the only purpose is to make your code easily readable to yourself and others.

Comment: I always put clean() above the particular clean_fieldname() functions, but that's about the only difference from Models. I didn't know about the coding styles. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @ArgsKwargs: So then, save() before or after clean(), for example? I often have 300 line `Form`s with complex functions, and would therefore like some standardization as to their positions, even though I know it's not the end of the world.

Comment: @pastylegs: No problem, it's a great guide to have when you aim to be a great Django developer

Comment: If im not mistaken django first checks the individual clean methods, then does a full clean and I believe theres a third step.. So actually individual cleans should come first I suppose :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of django's model style guide lines derive from python's [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines, so if you haven't done it yet have a look there! There aren't any specific guidelines for forms, but it's a good practice for sure to apply the [rules for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) to forms as well if possible (eg. order of the inner meta class).

But probably the most important point here is to keep some consistency over your whole project, so that eg. other developers wouldn't miss a certain method definition in long form class if they are expecting it at a certain point... But I guess everybody will agree that form classes tend to get very complex and there aren't any official guildelines for them!

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks for the answer, I think it was worth asking just to find whether I'm the only one unaware of a standardized style! Luckily not :)